# Ubuntu intallation is stuck at vmware tools installation

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

I installed unbuntu 12.04 LTS in VMware workstation 7.0 and the VMware used the "Easy Mode".
When I finish the intallation, the VMware automatically installed the VMware Tools, and it was stuck at this scene.
The scene is like this:

```
******************************************************************
******************************************************************
Vmware Easy Install

PLEASE WAIT! VMware Tools is currently being 
installed on your system. Depending on the 
version of Ubuntu you are installing, you may 
log in below and use the system during 
intallation. Otherwise, please wait for the 
graphical environment to launch. Thank you.

******************************************************************
******************************************************************
ubuntu login:_
```

I can login and use the command "sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm start" to go to the graphical interfaces， but I have to do it every time I use this system.

And I have waited for a very long time and VMware still told me to wait.....

Any Solutions?

Comment: This [link](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2014/07/resolving-issue-with-ubuntu.html) might help.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

**Follow the 3 Steps ...**

1. Restore the `/etc/issue` file:

   `sudo mv /etc/issue.backup /etc/issue`
2. Restore the `/etc/rc.local` file:

   `sudo mv /etc/rc.local.backup /etc/rc.local`
3. Restore the `/etc/init/lightdm.conf` file:

   `sudo mv /opt/vmware-tools-installer/lightdm.conf /etc/init`

Then reboot.

Comment: Your answer [reads very much like this answer on Ask Ubuntu.](http://askubuntu.com/a/127107/42169)

Comment: There's a very critical typo in this post. There is a * added after /etc/issue which needs to be removed.

Comment: I had this problem as well, and this solution worked. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome ! worked for me

Comment: In my case, Ubuntu 10.10, maveric, the last file is gdm.conf instead of lightdm.conf

Comment: Worked perfectly for me with Ubuntu 13.10. Thanks much!

Answer (score 12):

I just had the same issue with Worksattion 7 and Ubuntu 12.04.

I tried the suggested solutions, however they did not work.

What worked for me was Creating the VM first by choosing the option "I will install the OS later"

then mount the iso on the CDROM through the settings window and boot it up.

Worked 1st time.

also once its finished copying the files disconnect the cd rom at reboot

Comment: This method worked for me too.

Comment: Same here, this method worked perfectly

Answer (score 6):

Here is an alternative approach:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/126229/12-04-stuck-at-vmare-easy-install

I did not test it - no priority now - but do experience the same issue. As I only use Ubuntu for some testing it is not that bad, but strange. Have been installing Ubuntu since 6.06 LTS in VMWare and never had this problem (did have other issues though ;-) )

Answer (score 3):

when it goes to the VMWare easy install it try to install the autoinst.iso, what you need to do is to disconnected the disk and the image disk as well, that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

An even easier and clean way to fix this is is shut down your VM, go to properties and remove the floppy drive. Then start it and voila!

Answer (score 0):

Same thing is happening to me. I don't quite have a solution (other than maybe calling startx instead of the lightdm), but I do have something that seemed like it should've worked, so maybe it'll help out in some way. (most of this is just what it tells you to do).

Make sure you take a snapshot before you start.

I started up the vm, disconnected my virtual CD-Drive, went to Vm > Install VMWareTools, and hit install.
Then, I mounted the cd-rom drive, extracted the tarball to my desktop, and ran the .pl script in there. It then went through installation settings (I just used all default) and finally said it was done and I should log-out and log back in.

VMWare seems to think VMWare-tools is installed, but the screen still shows up, and now the mouse cannot click on pop-up windows (like the shutdown window). I need to revert, but I'll try it again, this time reading what installation settings I'm using.